# Thunderbird & Postbox: Problem in sending emails

Tags: thunderbird, imap, postbox

I am using paid version of Postbox and thunderbird both have problem in sending emails. Sending mail progress keeps loading. I have around 50+ IMAP email addresses sometimes mail send successfully and sometimes it stuck. Initially I thought it is my mail server problem but later when I used softwares thebat and em Client I found its a thunderbird and postbox problem and I believe they both are from same vendor.

I have set max imap connections 5 and http connections 5.

Can any one guide me how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sending email is done using SMTP, _not_ IMAP or HTTP.

Comment: yes i set max connection just in case if it reaches max connection limit and server deny sending email.